# How to create a split button in Ant Design?

Tags: antd

We need to implement a split button in Ant Design React UI. It already provides Button component which doesn't support splitting. It also has Dropdown that can split button as shown in example - https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-brahmagupta-us4kv

The problem of this implementation is that the dropdown will be closed if you click on it. This is OK for menu, but we need to put a more complex form there. It should be closed when you click outside of the dropdown, but not when you click inside.

Is this possible with Ant Design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired behavior is best achievable with [`Tooltip`](https://ant.design/components/tooltip/#header), with it you can render any custom component.

By design, `DropDown` should render a `Menu` and not a custom component like you did as it accepts a `Menu` type according to docs.

Comment: Dennis, the question with Tooltip is to which component it shouild be assigned. It should be displayed by click on the right part of split button. And the problem is that in Ant Design there's no split button per se, except Dropdown.

Comment: Split button is `Button.Group`.